# How can I get the list of modules required by a package?

Tags: perl

I'm writing an extension for Mo*se class system and I need to get the list, from inside a package, of all modules required by the package using the "use" statement. 
I tried to inspect the %INC data struct, but I get the list of ALL modules loaded at compile time, and I cannot filter out the modules loaded by my package.
I guess I have to deal with the Perl debugger, but any suggestion will be really appreciated :-)

Eg:

```
package MyApp 0.001 ;
use Module1 ;
use Module2 ;
...
sub list_requested_modules {
    ...HOW TO DO IT ???
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't distinguish between modules loaded in the current file or modules that were already loaded. Consider if you have "use Module1;" but Module1 was already loaded, so all that does is import to the current package from the already-loaded module. Where would you then consider that module was loaded from?

Two things you can do depending what you are trying to figure out: you can parse a file to guess what modules it requires (though it doesn't guarantee they'll be loaded from there, they could be already loaded as I mentioned before). A good tool for this is [Perl::PrereqScanner::Lite](https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl::PrereqScanner::Lite). You can use the [`__FILE__`](https://perldoc.pl/functions/__FILE__) literal to get the name of the current file.

```
use Perl::PrereqScanner::Lite;
my @required = Perl::PrereqScanner::Lite->new->scan_file(__FILE__)->required_modules;
```

The other option is to track what modules are loaded yourself. At the very beginning of the file put this:

```
my %original_inc;
BEGIN { %original_inc = %INC }
```

Then either immediately afterward, to find any modules loaded during compile time (including `use` statements), or in a later subroutine, you can compare how %INC changed:

```
my @newly_loaded = grep { !exists $original_inc{$_} } keys %INC;
```

In addition to the previously mentioned caveat that modules may have already been previously required and thus already present in %INC, modules you load may load other modules in turn, so the difference is probably not going to exactly match what `use` statements are in the file.

EDIT: Personally I would avoid both of these methods by obviating the need for such logic in the first place. Instead of loading your modules with `use`, write a subroutine that loads them using [Module::Runtime](https://metacpan.org/pod/Module::Runtime) and keeps track of what you load with it in some manner, and call that for each module in a BEGIN block. But note that this would defeat automated prereq scanning such as the PrereqScanner module I mentioned above.

Comment: If they want to find what's loaded by a particular module then the second query of `%INC`  also need run in `BEGIN`, or they get everything -- `BEGIN { ... }; use Module; BEGIN { ... }`

Comment: @Grinnz, That won't report modules that are loaded by MyApp that but were previously loaded (false negatives), and it will report modules not directly loaded by MyApp (false positives)

Comment: Thank you @grinnz for your detailed response, the double query on %INC it's a really appreciated and interesting hack.

Comment: @ikegami that's why I presented the two options. It depends what you consider "required by the package". Though I'd consider the self-prereq-scanning method to be a rather hacky option.

Answer (score 1):

Another option, if you're *only* interested in knowing what modules the current file will load/has loaded would be [PPI](https://metacpan.org/pod/PPI):

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use Data::Dumper;
use PPI;
require Mock::Sub;

my $ppi_doc  = PPI::Document->new(__FILE__);
my $ppi_deps = $ppi_doc->find('PPI::Statement::Include');

for (@$ppi_deps){
    print $_->module . "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
warnings
strict
Data::Dumper
PPI
Mock::Sub
```

Comment: This is basically a simplified version of [Perl::PrereqScanner](https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl::PrereqScanner). The Lite alternative exists because it is very slow.